# ubuntu virtual machine manager: how to preserve the host name and the IP address when cloning

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to clone a centos VM. I've found that cloning it does not preserve the host name and does not preserve the IP address. The host name is reverted to localhost.localdomain and the assigned IP address is always new.
Is there any way to clone a VM preserving all networking parameters?

Related package versions:

```
virt-manager                                          0.9.5-1ubuntu3 
libvirt0                                              1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.10
```

Comment: What version of libvirt and virt-manager are you using? Yes, this can be done, but I need to know what versions so I can be sure the option is visible via a GUI application like that.

Comment: Updated question with additional info